# To prove the following Theorems related to Greatest integer function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality

if $[x]$ denotes greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ prove that

$$A= [x]+\left[x+\frac{1}{n}\right]+\left[x+\frac{2}{n}\right]+\cdots+\left[x+\frac{n-1}{n}\right]=[nx]$$

$$B= \left[\frac{n+1}{2}\right]+\left[\frac{n+2}{4}\right]+\left[\frac{n+4}{8}\right]+\cdots=n $$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I tried $A$ like this:

Using $[x+y] \ge [x]+[y]$ we have

$$\left[x+\frac{1}{n}\right] \ge [x]$$

$$\left[x+\frac{2}{n}\right] \ge [x]$$

$$\left[x+\frac{3}{n}\right] \ge [x]$$ and so on

so $$A \ge n[x]$$  also

$[x] \le x$  so we have

$$\left[x+\frac{1}{n}\right] \le x+\frac{1}{n}$$

$$\left[x+\frac{2}{n}\right] \le x+\frac{2}{n}$$

$$\left[x+\frac{3}{n}\right] \le x+\frac{3}{n}$$ adding all

$$A \le nx+\frac{n-1}{2}$$ so

$$n[x] \le A \le nx+\frac{n-1}{2}$$  help me to continue here.

For $B$ i tried in similar way but could not prove.

Answer (score 2):

Hint for $(A)$:

> Write $[nx]=nq+r$ with $0\leq q<n$. Then $q+\frac{r}{n}\leq x<q+\frac{r+1}{n}$. When is $x+\frac{k}{n}\geq x+1$?

Hint for $(B)$:

> Prove by induction on $n$, showing first for $n=1$, then for $m$ show if true for $n=m$, then true for $n=2m$ and $n=2m+1$.

Comment: I could not understand clue you gave for $A$ can you give some more details

Comment: what i tried to understand is if $x$ is of the form $x=q+f$ where $q$ is integer and $f$ is a positive fraction lying in $(0 \:\: 1)$ then we have $[nx]=[nq+nf]=nq+[nf]$ so did you assume $r=[nf]$

Comment: No, I assumed a principle of number theory, that given any integers $a,b$ with $b\neq 0$, there are integers $q,r$ with $a=bq+r$, with $0\leq r<|b|$. This is commonly called the "division algorithm." However, it is true that $r=[nf]$, as you stated. That's not particularly relevant to the hint, however. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division